Does Spotify's voyager library support StringIndexes in Python?
There's a spotify blog article stating that voyager supports string-based identifiers.
The Voyager python API doesn't mention anything about that though...
The Voyager Java API does have a StringIndex.
Is the Python API not providing the same functionality or is it just the documentation that is not up-to-date?
